Can’t Post Purchases via QuickBooks Online REST API
I’m trying to add purchases to QBO, but no matter how I change the package, it keeps failing. Here’s the JSON package currently being sent to https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/{{companyId}}/purchase?minorversion=70:
{
    "AccountRef" : { "value" : "95" },
    "Line" : 
    [
    {
        "AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail" : 
        {
            "AccountRef" : { "value" : "95" },
            "BillableStatus" : "NotBillable"
        },
        "Amount" : 30.15,
        "DetailType" : "AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail",
        "LineNum" : 1
    }
    ],
    "PaymentType" : "Check"
}

I’ve tweaked the package many different ways, but the response is always the same:
{
    "Fault" : 
    {
        "Error" : 
        [
        {
            "Detail" : "Property Name:failed to parse json object; a property specified is unsupported or invalid",
            "Message" : "Request has invalid or unsupported property",
            "code" : "2010"
        }
        ],
        "type" : "ValidationFault"
    },
    "time" : {{timestamp}}
}

Anyone know what I’m doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!
